# UNITY: Trying to create a Baked Lighiting map and I have problems when the progress

Tags: unity-game-engine

I am new in Unity.

I'm following the Unity Learn tutorials.

I'm stuck on one: Bakering or creating a lightmap.

The thing is that it stays stuck "preparing the bakering" (6%), whether I use Progressive GPU or Progressive CPU. It does not advance more in any of the two, and the calculation of hours begins to go up and up and up and up.... but the percentage of advance does not.

I don't understand what's going on because it's a very simple test scenario with just a few lights to bake.

What am I doing wrong?

Thanks for your answers!

I follow all the steps:

**1.-** **I check that the lights I want to be baked have, in the Inspector window:**

**1.a.-** checked the "Static" checkbox, and

**1.b.-** In Light > General > Type: "Area (baked only).

In the "Light Explorer" window I also check that the mode of the lights that I want to bake are in "Baked".

**2.- In Window > Rendering > lighting:**

**2.a.-** In the "Scene" tab, I press "New lighting settings", save it in Assets > Lighting and call it <<MyFirstLightmap>> (or whatever I want).

**2.b.-** I change the lighting mode to "Backed indirect".

**2.c.-** I can use a) Progressive GPU (only if my HW & SW support it) and b) Progressive CPU.

I have to say that I have tried with both.

**2.d.-** I select "Generate Lighting".

The thing is that it stays stuck "preparing the bakering" (6%), whether I use Progressive GPU or Progressive CPU. It does not advance more in any of the two, and the calculation of hours begins to go up and up and up and up.... but the percentage of advance does not.

I don't understand what's going on because it's a very simple test scenario with just a few lights to bake.

What am I doing wrong?

Thanks for your answers!